# Why is the scroll position of the list initialized?

Tags: swiftui

When the button is clicked, a translucent view appears.

However, at this moment, there is an issue where the scroll position of the list is initialized.

[Image 1: Before button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRmV9.png)

[Image 2: After button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGJmW.png)

Below is my SwiftUI code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isButtonClicked: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Layer 0
            TabView {
                tableView()
                    .tabItem { Text("Tab Label 1") }
                    .tag(1)
                Text("Tab Content 2")
                    .tabItem { Text("Tab Label 2") }
                    .tag(2)
            }
        
            // Layer 1
                VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        isButtonClicked.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Button")
                    })
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 20.0)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 60.0)
        
            // Layer 2
            TranslucentView(opacity: 0.6)
                .opacity(isButtonClicked ? 1.0 : 0)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isButtonClicked.toggle()
                }
                .animation(.linear(duration: 0.3))
        }
    }
}

struct TranslucentView: View {
    let opacity: Double

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .opacity(opacity)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct tableView: View {
    let items = [
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 1),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 3),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 5),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 2),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 9),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 4),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 7),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 2),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 1),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 3),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 8),
        Item(name: "Apple", counts: 1),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            VStack {
                Text(item.name)
                Text(String(item.counts))
            }
        }
    }
}

class Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let counts: Int

    init(name: String, counts: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.counts = counts
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

*The transparent view must cover the entire screen including the tab bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On state change the `body` is rebuilt, so `tableView` is recreated, so reinitialised. To avoid last we need to make view equatable, so rendering engine do not recreate it on external changes.

Here is a solution (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

[image: demo]

```
TabView {
    EquatableView(content: tableView())       // << here !!
        .tabItem { Text("Tab Label 1") }
        .tag(1)
    Text("Tab Content 2")
        .tabItem { Text("Tab Label 2") }
        .tag(2)
}
```

and conform `tableView` to `Equatable` as follows

```
struct tableView: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: tableView, rhs: tableView) -> Bool {
        true
    }
    
    let items = [
     // ... other code
```